# Can't write YUV Frame from ffmpeg into .yuv file

Tags: c, c++11, ffmpeg, yuv

My goal is to write the frame I decode into a file. I know I capture it well because it shows in my SDL playback and I encode it afterwards without any problems. Yet it seems I can't write the frame into a file properly. Here is the code :

```
#define PIXFMT AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720
// initialize SWS context for software scaling

sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
    pCodecCtx->height,
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    PIXFMT,
    SWS_LANCZOS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

FfmpegEncoder enc("rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream", pParser);
//SetPixelArray();

i = 0;
enc.FillYuvImage(pFrameRGB, 0, this->pCodecCtx->width, this->pCodecCtx->height);
FILE *pFile;
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0 && !exit) {
    if (packet.stream_index == videoindex) {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        if (frameFinished) {

            i++;
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
            if (i < 500)
            {
                pFile = fopen(std::string("./screenshots/screen.yuv").c_str(), "a+");
                for (int y = 0; y < pCodecCtx->height; y++)
                {
                    fwrite(pFrame->data[0] + y * pFrame->linesize[0], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height, pFile);
                    fwrite(pFrame->data[1] + y * pFrame->linesize[1], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4, pFile);
                    fwrite(pFrame->data[2] + y * pFrame->linesize[2], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4, pFile);
                }
                fclose(pFile);
            }
            enc.encodeFrame(pFrameRGB);
        }
    }
    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

The program crashes when it tries to write the frame.

Comment: Check if fopen is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for all your comments and answers !
Here is the fixed code :

```
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0 && !exit && i < 1000) {
    if (packet.stream_index == videoindex) {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        if (frameFinished) {

            i++;
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
            if ((pFile = fopen(std::string("./screenshots/screen.yuv").c_str(), "ab")) == NULL)
                continue;
            fwrite(pFrameRGB->data[0], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height, pFile);
            fwrite(pFrameRGB->data[1], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4, pFile);
            fwrite(pFrameRGB->data[2], 1, pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4, pFile);
            fclose(pFile);
            enc.encodeFrame(pFrameRGB);
        }
    }
    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

I was using the wrong frame before, aswell as wrong data and size.

Comment: This can produce wrong results; individual lines in the planes are not guaranteed to be contiguous so you cannot write them as a single block of data. IIRC libavutil will "pad" allocated picture so that each line is aligned to 32 bytes. It will work for 1280x720 but might fail for different resolutions (try video with some "odd" dimensions like 258x142).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment, you need to check if fopen is successful.

But I think issue is you are writing more than what is present in buffer. I know limitted knowledge about yuv. I think you should do the following. This is based on my understanding from the *Single Frame YUV420* picture in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV420p_.28and_Y.E2.80.B2V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion).

```
abcfor (int y = 0; y < pCodecCtx->height; y++) //plane 0: same width and height
{
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0] + y * pFrame->linesize[0], 1, pCodecCtx->width, pFile);
}


for (int y = 0; y < pCodecCtx->height/4; y++) //plane1: Same width and quarter height.
{
    fwrite(pFrame->data[1] + y * pFrame->linesize[1], 1, pCodecCtx->width, pFile);
}

for (int y = 0; y < pCodecCtx->height/4; y++) //plane2: Same width and quarter height.
{
    fwrite(pFrame->data[2] + y * pFrame->linesize[2], 1, pCodecCtx->width, pFile);
}
```

Please note, the order of writing depends on the colour format. I want you to focus on the number of loop iterations and number of bytes in `fwrite()` in each iteration.

Comment: YUV420P has `height` lines each `width` wide for plane 0 and `height`/2 lines each `width`/2 wide for planes 1 and 2. But `.yuv` extension usually means YUV444P pixel format... And even in YUV420P it probably would be planar and not line-interleaved chroma.

Comment: You mean, for plane1 and plane2, for loop is from 0 to height/2 and do fwrite width/2 bytes?

Comment: Yes exactly. Planes 1 and 2 are half the size of plane 0 in each direction.

Comment: Ok made the changes. I know about YUV420SP. There will be two planes, 2nd plane will have same width but half the height. Anyway, thanks for educating me. :)

Comment: That one is called NV21 in ffmpeg. I think the code is still wrong because for 420P it should be writing each plane separately, first 0 then 1 then 2. At least yuv files I saw with 444P format were in that layout.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin Oh yes. Now it should be proper. If anything is wrong please edit them.

Comment: I tried this code but it fails the same way. Everytime I want to write pFrame->data[1] and pFrame->data[2] it segfault

Comment: @tankyx: can you try this? For both plane1 and plane2, make"for (...,y < pCodecCtx->height/4;..)" and fwrite(...,pCodecCtx->width,..). Do not change plane0. Let me know the result. Anyway, I have updated it in my answer.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin: Hey we were wrong. Please see the picture in the wikipedia link I have provided in the updated answer. I have corrected my code.

Comment: @MayurK no we weren't. Planes 1 and 2 are definitely half the width of plane 0. I even double-checked in debugger and linesize values for 720x576 YUV420P video were `[768, 384, 384]`.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin: Is it? I don't understand that picture then. Could you explain it wrt to that picture briefly?

Comment: That picture is misleading or even plain wrong (especially when stride is not the same as width). Surprisingly, I wasn't able to find really good introduction to YUV pictures (there are many but all are wrong/incomplete in one aspect or another). Here is better picture: http://i.afterdawn.com/storage/pictures/dvf_color_02.jpg . It's as simple as that - each 2x2 pixel block in Y plane corresponds to single pixel in U and V planes; so in that picture Y plane is 4x4, and U and V planes are 2x2. Half of lines, half of columns.